# Proguard on multimodule app

Tags: android, proguard

I have an app that consists of following modules:

```
/app
/common
/customviews
/model
```

Now I want to obfuscate my code for production, so I put the following lines on all my `build.gradle` files for all modules.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

This file contains the following rules:

```
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**


-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8


-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

The app compiles fine, however when running it I get the following exception:

```
b.g.b.a.ac: Incorrect resolution sequence for Java constructor public constructor a() defined in com.myexample.myapp.model.a.e.a[b@eb11a88] (b.g.b.a.a.d.a.f.a.j: class com.myexample.myapp.model.a.e.a)
       at b.g.b.a.ai.a(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.o.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.l$a$e.b(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.l$a$e.a(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.ae$a.a(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.ae$c.a(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.l$a.e(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.b.a.l.h(Unknown Source)
       at b.g.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.b.a.r.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.b.a.v.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.b.a.d$1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.b.a.d$1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.b.a.v.a(Unknown Source)
       at e.b.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
       at e.n.a(Unknown Source)
       at e.n.b(Unknown Source)
       at e.o$a.c(Unknown Source)
       at e.o$a.a(Unknown Source)
       at e.n.a(Unknown Source)
       at e.n$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
       at $Proxy1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.myexample.myapp.model.b.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.myexample.myapp.ui.splash.SplashViewModel.f(Unknown Source)
       at com.myexample.myapp.ui.splash.SplashActivity.k(Unknown Source)
       at com.myexample.myapp.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I am using Kotlin by the way.

EDIT: new exception:

```
6-13 10:17:37.884 24129-24129/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.android, PID: 24129
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.myapp.android.model.api.userprofile.UserProfile
        for method d.a
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.myapp.android.model.api.userprofile.UserProfile
        for method d.a
        at retrofit2.n$a.a(ServiceMethod.java:755)
        at retrofit2.n$a.c(ServiceMethod.java:741)
        at retrofit2.n$a.a(ServiceMethod.java:172)
        at retrofit2.m.a(Retrofit.java:170)
        at retrofit2.m$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
        at $Proxy1.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.myapp.android.model.repository.impl.c.a(UserRepositoryImpl.kt:23)
        at com.myapp.android.ui.splash.SplashViewModel.f(SplashViewModel.kt:20)
        at com.myapp.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity.m(SplashActivity.kt:58)
        at com.myapp.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
            ... 9 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/collections/collections.kotlin_builtins
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsPackageFragmentProviderKt.a(builtInsPackageFragmentProvider.kt:39)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.c(KotlinBuiltIns.java:138)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.platform.JvmBuiltIns.<init>(JvmBuiltIns.kt:56)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.platform.JvmBuiltIns.<init>(JvmBuiltIns.kt:31)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.reflect.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.a(RuntimeModuleData.kt:47)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ModuleByClassLoaderKt.a(moduleByClassLoader.kt:58)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.b(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:37)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.a(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:34)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.a(ReflectProperties.java:93)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.a(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.m(Unknown Source:7)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.b(KClassImpl.kt:42)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.a(KClassImpl.kt:39)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.a(ReflectProperties.java:93)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.a(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.a(Unknown Source:7)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.f(KClassImpl.kt:159)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.b(KClassImpl.kt:173)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.b(KClassImpl.kt:86)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.a(KClassImpl.kt:39)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.a(ReflectProperties.java:93)
06-13 10:17:37.885 24129-24129/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.a(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.e(Unknown Source:7)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.i(KClassImpl.kt:192)
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.a(KClasses.kt:40)
        at com.squareup.moshi.k.a(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:160)
        at com.squareup.moshi.n.a(Moshi.java:100)
        at retrofit2.a.a.a.a(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
        at retrofit2.m.a(Retrofit.java:330)
        at retrofit2.m.b(Retrofit.java:313)
        at retrofit2.n$a.c(ServiceMethod.java:739)
            ... 22 more
```

Comment: You only have to obfuscate the app module. This also obfuscates any libraries used by the app. You only have to obfuscate libraries if you want to publish them separately - and even then I wouldn't really recommend it. Most libraries don't do that. So set `minifyEnabled` to false in your library modules and see if it works.

Comment: Still happens...

Comment: Your issue relates to configuration issues regarding the _Json_ models. Could you provide insights to the relevant implementations? Maybe `UserRepositoryImpl.kt:23` or `UserProfile`?

Comment: obfuscate log and check read plain log for more info.for how to obfuscated code https://androidteachers.com/android/how-decode-an-obfuscated-stack-trace-logs-in-android/

Answer (score 37):

*Proguard* is only relevant for the actual release. So instead of adding `minifyEnabled true` for every module, only add it for to the release configuration of the app itself.

All code coming from libraries (regardless if from a module or an external dependency) will be obfuscated with the code of the application.

If you have custom rules you'd like to share with your library, you can define the `consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'` to be added to the `AAR` file.

Comment: I did just that, but get the same problem

Comment: I am getting a new exception now after allowing some moshi classes

Comment: Could you give some information about the code which is actually failing? It seems that you're missing some _Proguard_ rules.

Comment: It would be nice to link sources of that information. Without it one can not be sure in that being true

Comment: @KirillStarostin I'm not sure of which parts you refer to. Most information you'll find directly or indirectly on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add Proguard file to library module, you should add it to the correct property which is [`consumerProguardFiles`](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations) and not `proguardFiles`, inside the defaultConfig block of your library's build.gradle file. E.g.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minifyEnabled true
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    ...
}
```

`proguardFiles` works for application module and not with library modules.

Comment: I just want to make it work, I thought minifying the app would minify the library modules as well?

Comment: Use right property 'consumerProguardFiles' for library module and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The initial error you were getting is similar to the one described in [KotlinReflectionInternalError when attempting to create an adapter for a data class](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/394), and can be solved by adding the following to the ProGuard rules:

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
   public <methods>;
}
```

For the second error, add this rule to ProGuard:

```
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }
```